# How to suppress SYSLIB0051 in a globl suppressions file

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-warnings, .net-8.0

In some generated code, which I cannot change and for which I cannot modify the generator, after updating to .NET 8, I get a number of SYSLIB0051 warnings. I thought it should be straightforward to suppress them using a global suppressions file.

However, I cannot find the correct Category (maybe "Compiler"?), CheckId, and maybe MessageId and Scope that the `SuppressMessageAttribute` requires.

How can I suppress this message in a global suppressions file and/or where can I find the necessary information?

Comment: You could set `<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);SYSLIB0051</NoWarn>` in the project file(s) if you want to unconditionally turn it off.

Comment: @MartinCostello I'd prefer to not turn it off unconditionally.

Comment: SuppressMessageAttribute does not apply to compiler diagnostics.

Comment: @Lukas No, I'm using `<NoWarn>` although I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `#pragma` directives around the code causing the issues if you want to target specific areas of concern.

For example in your case, wrap the line(s) with:

```
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0051
// "bad" code here
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0051
```

Comment: The code is generated, and I cannot modify the generated code nor the generator.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that part. 